# Google Forms, sidebar for live form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to create a sidebar to a live google form, ideally in order to pick from a (google) map coordinates to be entered in the form.

From the documentation and from my trials I can create a sidebar to the form editor/designer (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/ID/edit), not the live form itself (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/ID/viewform). Forms are different in regard to the Doc and Sheet Apps, that there exist these two views.

For example:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar')
      .setTitle('Maps');
  FormApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

First problem is that the trigger for `onOpen()` fires when opening the form designer, not when the end user will open the form (/viewform URL) to fill it out.

Then `FormApp.getUI().showSidebar(ui);` gets the UI of the forms designer and opens up a sidebar there and not in the Form the end user has to fill out.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getUi%28%29) seems to confirm this.

So, is it possible to get access to the live form, including any associated triggers?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=google+form+sidebar

Comment: @teatimer I might not have been clear on the distinction between form editor and live form. Please check my improved question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is it possible to get access to the live form, including any
>   associated triggers?

No

However, you could embed your form in a page that also hosts the map in a separate frame, enabling users to browse the map, click to see coordinates, and then copy them to the form. There would be no interaction between the google-hosted form and the map.

Comment: I expected as much, as I was trying to find a solution for about a week. Just thought I might have overlooked something, as I am new with GApps Script.